Find X in inscribed angle using the circle arc theorem
I've been recently working on a question from my my math book, and what seemed to be a simple problem to solve in under 5 minutes using a regular solution, turned out to have multiple paths to the answer which confused me, until I took a unusual path to the solution, which I find a bit verbose:
$3x + 2x = 5x \\ 5x + x = 6x \\ \arc A = 12x \\x \times 2 = 6x = arc B] \to \arc A + arc B = \huge \circ  = 12x + 6x = 18x \to \\360 \div 18 = x = 20$.
Find X.

I am not seeking the outright answer to this problem, I would like to know about the numerous different ways it can be solved, especially using the Triangle exterior angle theorem.

What is the unusual path that you found confusing and unclear?

In the diagram, what is the symbol before 2 of the x's? It almost looks like a backwards 7.

I am only guessing what $arcA$ and $arcB$ are. For another tool, observe that the opposite interior angles of a cyclic quadrilateral sum to $180^\circ$, so $3x+6x = 180^\circ$.

@CalvinLin Eastern Arabic numerals

Are you sure about your statement?
Here's my drawing of the situation:

According to you, angles $G$, $H$ and $C$ are all equal to $x$.
As $CGF$ is a triangle, angle $F$ must be equal to $\pi - 2x$.
As $CDH$ is a triangle, angle $D$ must be equal to $\pi - 2x$.
As $CDEF$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, the sum of the opposed angles should be $\pi$, meaning:
$$\pi - 2x + (\pi - 2x) = \pi$$
Which comes down to:
$$x = \frac{\pi}{4}$$
Edit after comment from Gwen:
Apparently the numbers are different:

Angle $H = x$
Angle $G = 2x$
Angle $C = 3x$

In that case:

Angle $F = \pi - 5x$
Angle $D = \pi - 4x$

Again, because of the cyclic quadrilateral: $D + F = \pi$, meaning that $\pi - 5x + (\pi - 4x) = \pi$, meaning that $9x=\pi$ or $x=20°$ indeed.

No the diagram has really bad writing. They're actually 2x,3x and x. Made me baffled too. I was thinking that why isn't it isoceles if 2 angles are equal

@Gwen: then it's just a question of modifying the values in my answer. The reasoning still holds (nowhere did I use the fact that those angles are equal, I just used their values).

@Gwen: in the meantime I've adapted my answer. I guess you can remove the downvote now :-)

I'm really sorry but I had to. I upvoted you. I'm sorry once again :)

The unknown angles of two triangles, i.e. $180°-4x$ and $180°-5x$ are opposite angles of a cyclic quadrilateral. Hence
$$180°-4x+180°-5x=180°$$
Thus $180°=9x\implies x=20°$
